# What is a xx bit process?

Tags: 64-bit, process, 32-bit

Hardware-wise:

> Technically, the bit size of a computer can refer to several things,
>   such as the size of its CPU instructions or the amount of data the CPU
>   can read from memory.

This is ok, but what is a 32 bit or a 64 bit process?

What are the technical differences between them? Why would I bother running IntelliJ IDEA in 64 bit but not 32 bit? What changes?

Comment: @gronostaj I do not think so..

Comment: @KorayTugay - What questions are still unanswered after you read that question's answers.

Comment: @Ramhound Is it only about addressable memory?

Comment: @KorayTugay - Your questions are really broad.  So much so a Wikipedia article explains the differences.  So I am trying to understand where your knowledge starts and ends.  So its important to understand how the existing question doesn't help answer your questions.

Comment: I am more then willing to answer your question.  I just have to understand what your question is and how its not a duplicate of an existing already answered question.

Comment: @Ramhound My question is: Sometimes an application will have 32 bit and 64 bit versions. What possible differences there can be? Only memory space the app uses?

Comment: One huge difference is that a 64-bit process has the capability of using more memory compared to a 32-bit process which is limited to only 2GB unless Windows is started with a special flag indicating a process can use more but still limited to less then 4GB.

Comment: @Ramhound And thats it?